# Есть ли сис в данном предложении?

Tags: глаголы, сказуемые

Пахли они не то кипарисом, не то свежей доской..

Есть ли тут сис, или это пгс? ОЧЕНЬ сильно смущает стоящее в Т. п. сущ. Т. п - это же всегда часть сис....

Answer (score 2):

***Пахли они не то кипарисом, не то свежей доской.***

Нет там СИС, предикативная основа: ***пахли они***. Пахли (чем?) не то кипарисом, не то свежей доской.

Это однородные дополнения, союзная связь.

Для определения вида сказуемого прежде всего анализируется связка: это глаголы *быть, становиться, являться* и др.

Материал по теме: https://7lafa.com/pageanswer.php?id=294

Comment: Я знаю про связки, смутил именно падеж. Спасибо за разъяснение!

Comment: Материал по теме не нужен, я им, в принципе, владею) на практике всегда всё оказывается сложнее))

Comment: Кстати, знаменательные связки (пришел усталый,  спал одетый, упал мертвымй лингвисты определяют по-разному. Здесь глагол не является служебным компонентом в обычном понимании,  а выражает наряду с именем ПОЛНОЦЕННЫЙ предикативный признак (здесь невозможна замена связкой БЫТЬ). Поэтому  такие сказуемые могут считаться сочетанием простого сказуемого с предикативным определением (дуплексивом). Дуплексивы относятся одновременно к существительному и глаголу.

Comment: Это была для меня новая информация. Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Да, действительно, именительный и творительный падежи — основные падежные формы именной части сказуемого.
Однако только этого мало. Для того, чтобы сочетание «знаменательный глагол + имя» было составным именным сказуемым, должны соблюдаться следующие условия:
а) глагол можно заменить грамматической связкой *быть*;
б) саму связку можно сделать нулевой.

Он считался дураком. — Он был дураком. — Он дурак.
Она родилась птицей. — Она была птицей. — Она птица.

В нашем предложении такие "видоизменения" сделать невозможно — имеем подлежащее **они**, простое глагольное сказуемое **пахли** и два дополнения, объединённых повторяющимся союзом **то... то...**

[Составное именное сказуемое](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/704-15_sostavnoe_imennoe_skazuemoe.html)

Comment: А если - он спал мёртвым сном?) это ведь получается сис, и на связку "быть" тут не заменишь

Comment: Во-от! Это не СИС. Главное в этом предложении то, что _он **спал_.** Как? Каким образом? Мертвым сном или свернувшись калачиком. А вот **Он упал мертвым** — это СИС.

Comment: Хм.. Значит, всё и всегда зависит от связки и зря я пытаюсь огород городить.. Спасибо!!